# In how many ways can the word "kosmos" be arranged so that the same letters do not come together?

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can the word "kosmos" be arranged so that the same
>    letters do not come together? $(84)$

We have the word $k_1o_1s_1m_1o_2s_2$ - $6$ letters but two letters are of the same kind: $\dfrac{6!}{2!2!}=180$. How to approach the problem further? I am not completely sure I understand why we should divide $6!$ by $2!2!$. Can you clarify this for me? How to approach the problem further?

Comment: The problem is asking in how many arrangements of the letters of the word KOSMOS no two consecutive letters are identical.  Therefore, you must eliminate those arrangements in which the two O's are consecutive or the two S's are consecutive.  What makes this tricky is that cases in which two O's are consecutive may include cases in which two S's are consecutive and vice versa.

Comment: $84$ is the answer which you have to get?

Comment: @RebecaLieYatsuzukaSilva  That is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is the answer which you have to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We wish to find the number of arrangements of the letters of the word KOSMOS in no two identical letters are consecutive.  To do this, we can use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

The word KOSMOS has six letters, so we have six positions to fill.  We can fill two of the positions with O's in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways, two of the remaining four positions with S's in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, and fill the remaining two positions with the distinct letters K and M in $2!$ ways.  Hence, if there were no restrictions, we would have
$$\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}2! = \frac{6!}{2!4!} \cdot \frac{4!}{2!2!} \cdot 2! = \frac{6!}{2!2!}$$
One factor of $2!$ in the denominator represents the number of ways we could permute the two O's within a given arrangement without creating an arrangement that is distinguishable from the given arrangement.  The other factor of $2!$ in the denominator represents the number of ways we could permute the two S's within a given arrangement without creating an arrangement that is distinguishable from the given arrangement.

From these, we must subtract those arrangements in which two O's are consecutive or two S's are consecutive.

*Arrangements of the letters of the word KOSMOS in which the two O's are consecutive*:  We have five objects to arrange:  K, M, OO, S, S.  Choose two of the five positions for the S's, then arrange the remaining three distinct objects in the remaining three positions.

> This can be done in $$\binom{5}{2}3!$$ ways.

*Arrangements of the letters of the word KOSMOS in which the two S's are consecutive*:  We again have five objects to arrange:  K, M, O, O, SS.  By symmetry, there are the same number of arrangements in which the two S's are consecutive as there are arrangements in which the two O's are consecutive.

If we subtract those arrangements in which the two O's are consecutive and those arrangements in which the two S's are consecutive from the total, we will have subtracted those arrangements in which both the two O's are consecutive and the two S's are consecutive twice, once for each way we could have designated one of those pairs of consecutive identical letters as the pair of consecutive identical letters.  We only want to subtract them once, so we must add them back.

*Arrangements of the letters of the word KOSMOS in which the two O's are consecutive and the two S's are consecutive*:  We have four objects to arrange: K, M, OO, SS.  Arrange the four distinct objects in four positions.

> This can be done in $4!$ ways.

Applying the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle gives the number of admissible arrangements:

> $$\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}2! - 2\binom{5}{2}3! + 4!$$

Comment: Than you! I almost got it!

Comment: But why can we calculate the ways if there were no restrictions in this way?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it is because we are choosing positions for the letters.  Since KOSMOS has six letters, we choose two positions for the O's, two of the remaining four positions for the S's, one of the two remaining positions for the K, and fill the final open position with the M.  Choosing positions for each letter determines the arrangement.

Comment: Do we consider the fact that we have letters of the same kind?

Comment: Yes, since the two O's are identical, we only care which positions they occupy, not whether we fill a position with the first O or the second O.

Comment: So, this is the reason why we use combinations, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The string is short enough that we can solve the problem by breaking it into three cases

1. The $o$s and $s$s appear in the order "AABB". In that case, we need to place one of $k$ or $m$ between the first pair, and the other between the second pair to ensure that the numbers aren't consecutive. We are free to swap both the $o$ and $s$, and the $k$ and $m$, so there are $1\times2\times2 = 4$ possibilities for this configuration.
2. The $o$s and $s$s appear in the order ABBA. In that case we need to place one of the remaining letters between the two "B"s, and the last letter can go in any of five slots (there are only five slots to avoid double counting). We are free to swap as before, so there are $5\times 2\times2 = 20$ possibilities for this configuration
3. The $o$s and $s$s appear in the order "ABAB". In that case we are free to place $k$ and $m$ as we like, since there is no danger of having consecutive letters. We can place the $k$ first in one of 5 slots, and afterwards there are 6 slots for the $m$. We are free to swap the $o$s and $s$s, so there are $5\times 6\times 2 = 60$ possibilities for this configuration

In total, there are thus $4 + 20 + 60 = 84$ possibilities

Comment: The argument in the second case is a bit tricky.  That said, nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, we have 6 objects with 2 sets of objects with 2 equal members each. The total number of ways = $\dfrac {6!}{2!2!}$

Next, we count those with OO and SS. We first “tie” the objects with the same nature  together to form one unit, and there are two such units. There are 4! Ways to permute these 4 distinct units (namely K, M, O, S). Then, we “unite” the equal objects and let them permute among themselves. There are 2!2! ways. In total, there are 4!2!2! ways.

The no of ways that the same object must not be placed together is then $\dfrac {6!}{2!2!} –4!2!2! = 84$ .

Comment: It is not clear to me which arrangements you are subtracting or how you got your count of $4!2!2!$ for those arrangements.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig After combining the OO as one unit and also the SS as another unit, we have 4 distinct units (namely K, M, S, O) to be permuted. There are 4! Ways to permute them. The OO has 2! Ways to permute among themselves and 2! Ways for the SS after the untie action. In total, there are 4!2!2! ways.

Comment: That is incorrect.  If both O's are consecutive and both S's are consecutive, then there are only $4!$ arrangements.  You also have to eliminate those arrangements in which both O's are consecutive or both S's are consecutive.  What makes this tricky is that eliminating those arrangements in which both O's are consecutive also eliminates those arrangements in which both O's are consecutive and both S's are consecutive, and similarly for eliminating those arrangements in which both S's are consecutive.  This is why I used the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to solve the problem.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I can only agree with the "If ... then... " part.

Comment: What answer would your method give for the number of permutations of AABB in which no two consecutive letters are identical?  Based on your explanation, I obtain $\frac{4!}{2!2!} - 2!2!2! < 0$ rather than $2$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig For the A’s must sit together and also B’s must sit together, the outcomes are {AaBb, AabB, aABb, aAbBb, and the other 4 that start with B (or b)} = a total of 8. That matches 2!2!2!. The error comes from the first operand instead of the second.

Comment: There are only six arrangements of the letters $AABB$.  They are $$AABB, \color{blue}{ABAB}, ABBA, BAAB, \color{blue}{BABA}, BBAA$$  Therefore, it is not possible for eight arrangements to violate the restriction that adjacent letters are identical.  Your error was treating identical letters as if they were distinguishable, which they are not.   Also, notice that the total number of arrangements of the letters $AABB$ is $\binom{4}{2} = \frac{4!}{2!2!} = 6$ since such an arrangement is completely determined by choosing which two of the four positions in the word will be occupied by $A$'s.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, I am treating every object as distinct. In this example, at the beginning we have 24 (= 4!) distinct objects. In which, 8 (= 2!2!2!) of them, namely {AaBb, AabB, aABb, aAbB and the other 4 starting with an ‘B’ or ‘b’} do not meet the requirement. The remaining 16 (= 24 – 8) can be classified into 4 four-member groups. They are {ABAB, ABBA, BAAB, BABA} if the objects are now considered as not distinct. Maybe this method is not efficient and systematic as yours but the point that I want to made is the ‘tie-and untie’ method is a possible way of counting.

Comment: If every object were distinct in the original problem, you would have $6!$ rather than $\frac{6!}{2!2!}$ arrangements of the letters of the word KOSMOS.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig You are right about that.